# Cannot send invitation in iOS Developer program

Tags: ios, developer-program

I want to invite someone as team member to the iOS developer program. I tried `Invite Person` and `Bulk Invite` but the `Send Invitation` button has always

```
<a id="submitBtn" class="button right " onclick="return(false);"><span>Send Invitation</span></a>
```

Everything has been filled out but I cannot send the invitation. What is the problem here?

It is the same problem as described [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PELmqJYdIOcJ:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6310523%20&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=at&client=firefox-a). Haven't received a response from Apple yet ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I took was to use another e-mail address. One of the reason could be that I already had an account associated with that e-mail address. Or the name of the e-mail address was too long so that the regex failed. Don't know.

Answer (score 1):

When you fill the invitation form, you must specify *both* **iOS Developer Program** *and* **Safari Developer Program** access type. So if you forget to set Safari Developer Program to "No access" for instance, the button "Send Invitation" stays disabled.

Comment: Hmmm, currently I'm not enrolled in the Safari Developer Program. The solution I took was to use another e-mail address. One of the reason could be that I already had an account associated with that e-mail address. Or the name of the e-mail address was too long so that the regex failed. Don't know. But thanks for your input. I'll give it a try the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Select No Access on Safari Developer Program. You must select an option for Safari Developer Program even if it doesn't matter to you.